# Erro de ambiguidade em tempo de execução ao executar deploy no WildFly

Tags: demoiselle, wildfly

Ao tentar fazer o deploy do arquivo war no WildFly, está acontecendo um erro de ambiguidade de de injeção de dependência na classe HttpServletRequest.

Mais alguém está passando ou passou por isso?

Erro retornado pelo WildFly:

> Cannot upload deployment: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" =>
>   {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"infoconv-proxy-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\".WeldStartService"
>   => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"infoconv-proxy-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\".WeldStartService:
>   Failed to start service Caused by:
>   org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001409: Ambiguous
>   dependencies for type HttpServletRequest with qualifiers @Default at
>   injection point [BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 1 of
>   [BackedAnnotatedMethod] @Default @Produces public
>   br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.internal.producer.HttpSessionProducer.create(HttpServletRequest)
>   at
>   br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.internal.producer.HttpSessionProducer.create(HttpSessionProducer.java:53)
>   Possible dependencies: - Producer Method [HttpServletRequest] with
>   qualifiers [@Default @Any] declared as [[BackedAnnotatedMethod]
>   @Default @Produces public
>   br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.internal.producer.HttpServletRequestProducer.create()],
>   - WELD%AbstractBuiltInBean%infoconv-proxy-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/demoiselle-servlet-2.5.1.jar%HttpServletRequest
>   "}}

Arquivo `POM` do projeto:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>br.gov.serpro.infoconv</groupId>
<artifactId>infoconv-proxy</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name></name>
<description></description>
<url></url>

<parent>
    <groupId>br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle</groupId>
    <artifactId>demoiselle-rest-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>

    <!-- https://github.com/infoconv/infoconv-ws -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>br.gov.serpro.rfb.infoconv.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>infoconv-ws</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Demoiselle dependencies -->
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle</groupId> <artifactId>demoiselle-jpa</artifactId> 
        <scope>compile</scope> </dependency> -->
    <!-- Uncomment this dependency if you are using a JTA -->
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle</groupId> <artifactId>demoiselle-jta</artifactId> 
        <scope>compile</scope> </dependency> -->

    <!-- Jackson dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.9</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- GZip dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.tuckey</groupId>
        <artifactId>urlrewritefilter</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.4</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4</version>
        <!-- <exclusions> <exclusion> <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId> <artifactId>guava</artifactId> 
            </exclusion> </exclusions> -->
    </dependency>

    <!-- Tests dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>doclint-java8-disable</id>
        <activation>
            <jdk>[1.8,)</jdk>
        </activation>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifestEntries>
                    <Dependencies>com.jersey.jersey-server,com.jersey.jersey-client,com.jersey.jersey-json</Dependencies>
                </manifestEntries>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>

</build>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>component.internal</id>
        <name>SERPRO Component Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://archiva.desenv.serpro/repository/component-internal</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Informações do ambiente:

- JDK: 1.9
- JRE: 1.9
- Server: wildfly-10.0.0.Final
- SO: Windows 10

Comment: @gustavo, o Demoiselle segue a especificação  JEE6 e o WildFly 8 segue a especificação JEE7, isso pode estar relacionado com o erro.
Vou instalar o Jboss 7.1.1 e a JDK 1.7 e tentar fazer o deploy.

Answer (score 1):

Como algumas pessoas já apontaram, o Demoiselle 2.x segue a especificação JEE 6, enquanto o WildFly segue a especificação JEE 7, o que gera algumas incompatibilidades (além da questão do suporte ao Java 8 também).

Já se está trabalhando em uma versão do Demoiselle que siga a especificação JEE 7 e, consequentemente rode no WildFly. Por enquanto temos uma versão 3.0.0-ALPHA1-SNAPSHOT (que lançamos 17/06/2016). Ou seja, é apenas um embrião, um experimento, uma versão sabidamente sem todas as funcionalidades que pretendemos que tenha na versão final, com alguns bugs conhecidos, e que não possou por uma carga de testes mais robustos. Além disso, nem todas as funcionalidades presentes na versão 2.5.1 estão nessa versão; priorizamos segurança, persistência, paginação, configuração.

Porém, caso mesmo sabendo dessas limitações queira ir testando, verificando se realmente atende às suas necessidades (por ora, em relação a funcionar no WildFly) e dar feedbacks à equipe, sinta-se a vontade, já disponibilizamos nesta versão os dois arquétipos, JSF e HTML-REST, para que uma aplicação possa ser instanciada rapidamente. Os canais para esse feedback podem ser o tracker do projeto (https://demoiselle.atlassian.net/) caso queira reportar bugs ou sugerir melhorias e/ou novas funcionalidades, o github (https://github.com/demoiselle) caso tenha contribuições de código, a lista de emails ou o próprio stackoverflow caso queira discutir, postar dúvidas, etc.

Como é uma versão SNAPSHOT, ainda não está no repositório central do Maven. Por isso é necessário adicionar manualmente o repositório de SNAPSHOTS (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots) manualmente no pom do projeto que pretenda utilizá-lo. Os arquétipos tem o groupId:

> br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.archetypes

e artefactId:

> demoiselle-html-rest

e

> demoiselle-jsf-jpa

respectivamente.

Comment: Apenas para atualizar o status do projeto, informo que já foi lançada a versão 3.0.0-ALPHA1. Ou seja, não é mais preciso adicionar o repositório de SNAPSHOTS para rodar projetos com dependência dessa versão.

Comment: Valeu, grande @Emerson!

Comment: Massa, @Emerson!

Comment: Podes atualizar a resposta com essa informação de que o ALPHA já está publicado, Emerson?

Comment: Exemplo: http://pastebin.com/2Hze8XNw

Answer (score 0):

Também estou com esse problema, primeiro estava com o WildFly 8.0.0 ai troquei para o 8.2.1 e após o 9.0.2 e ambos o mesmo problema, estranho pois é o servidor padrão sem nenhuma modificação e apenas fazendo o deploy da aplicação Bookmark que é gerada pelo parent demoiselle-rest-parent versão 2.5.1 a 2.5.0 também gera esse problema.

Comment: Pois é, se ao menos tivéssemos contato direto com a equipe do Demoiselle, quem resolver primeiro, avisa o outro!

Comment: Então no WildFly 8.0.0 funcionava?

Comment: Eu estava vendo aqui se consigo falar com o Emerson Saito, um dos membros da equipe Demoiselle.

Comment: Testei no 8.0 deu o mesmo erro

Comment: Então @CesarDraw a versão 2.5.0 funciona no Jboss 7.1.1 mas a versão 2.5.1 do framework não pois ela específica o jdk7 e o Jboss 7.1.1 por um erro dele não inicia com o jdk7, essa é uma issue conhecida que foi corrigida só para o wildfly. 
Em outros testes o Jboss EAP 6.4 funciona qualquer versão do framework e roda sob o jdk7, só que esse é um servidor pago. Ai a necessidade de que o framework funcione com o wildfly, que é um projeto livre.

Comment: Grande @gustavo, eu consegui rodar o Joss 7.1.1 com a jdk1.7.0_75.
Agora, vou fazer os testes com a aplicação.

Comment: Na versão 3 já estão resolvendo o problema de CDI:
https://github.com/demoiselle/framework3/commit/3950a0c8abfc42a23810a9e6f2ae7a4d19a38939

Comment: Olá @CesarDraw, como você conseguiu rodar o jdk7 com o jboss 7.1.1 ? E a versão 3 já é stable ?

Comment: Uma das alterações que fiz foi no pom.xml, desabilitei o doclint para java 8:

amanhã te passo direito.
<additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>

Answer (score 0):

O Demoiselle 2.5 é JEE6, então ele rodará nos JBoss EAP 6.x e JBoss AS 7.x, as versões JBoss EAP 7 e Wildfly são JEE7, que serão compatíveis com a versão 3 do Demoiselle que será baseado na JEE7.

No caso do gerador, utilizo no vídeo (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=57kyX-nuKRQ) a versão JBoss EAP 6.4 (JEE6), que também funciona na JBoss AS 7.1.1, o ideal é usar o JDK7. Com esse ambiente vai funcionar muito bem, estamos preparando a evolução do gerador para sair com a nova do framework logo que a versão final seja liberada.

Comment: Quando sair o Gerador pra nova versão, avisa a gente, @PauloGladson!
Um abração!